# Azure AD - how to set app manifest properties programatically (accessTokenAcceptedVersion to v2 and signInAudience)?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-cli, azure-ad-powershell-v2

Is there a way to programatically via API to set the manifest property "accessTokenAcceptedVersion" to 2?  This is required due to issue explained [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/575) - our code is expecting the new STS, fails with:

> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The
>   audience is invalid"

due to being old sts:  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/.../".  Similarly looking to set the "signInAudience" property as well so that we can have our apps show up in B2C:

```
{
...
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,    
...
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",    
...
}
```

Not seeing anything in [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0), [cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest) or [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#application-entity)([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763036/azure-ad-app-updating-manifest-programmatically))

If i capture the portal network traffic i can see the PATCH to graph.windows.net/myorganization/aplicaitons/{GUID}?api-version=2.0 where it sets the JSON properties:

> "accessTokenAcceptedVersion":2,

and

> "signInAudience":"AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",

But it also sets some another property - and appears to be not documented way of doing things?

> "logo@odata.mediaContentType":"application/json;odata=minimalmetadata"

and the signinaudience change sets:

> "supportsConvergence":true,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out the `beta` Graph APIs:

- [Application Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-beta)
- [API property of application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/apiapplication?view=graph-rest-beta)
- SignInAudience is direct property of the application object
- [Update Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Please note that this is still only available under the beta API of the Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Able to set both `accessTokenAcceptedVersion ` & `signInAudience` through Graph API.

Comment: Added a separate answer to handy for others.

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti is it possible via powershell?

Comment: @AmalPs as per microsoft documentation it's possible. But, I never tried.

Answer (score 1):

By using the below code snippet, able to set both `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` & `signInAudience` as desired.

```
ApiApplication api = new ApiApplication();
api.requestedAccessTokenVersion = 2;

Application application = new Application();
application.displayName = oAuthClientVO.getClientName();
application.signInAudience = "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount";
application.api = api;
```

For this, used the below libraries.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
    <version>[5.4.0,)</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>[1.3.6,)</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: nice idea, I will use this next time!  Those version strings look a bit dodgy though - are you sure they are correct?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. Now our code moved to prod as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish setting the `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion" = 2`  you can try something like this

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<app objectId>"
az rest --method PATCH --uri '$uri' --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body '{\""api\"":{\""requestedAccessTokenVersion\"":2}}'
```

This would work.

Nb: if you are facing some error like this

> ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.

you can try with login using this code.

```
 az login --service-principal --username ${your_client_id} --password ${your_client_secret} --tenant ${your_app_tenant_id}
```

Hope this helps someone in future.

Happy Coding :)