# Access Token Issuer from Azure AD is sts.windows.net Instead Of login.microsoftonline.com

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to validate an access token obtained from azure active directory.

I obtained the token from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{my tenant guid}}/v2.0`

The issuer in the token that comes back is `https://sts.windows.net//{{my tenant guid}}/`  which doesn't match.

If I check that config at `.well-known/openid-configuration`   the issuer is as expected `https://login.microsoftonline.com/....`

I've found a similar issue reported on git hub here https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/560

The advice is to manually edit the manifest's json in the application registration in AAD and set `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2`.

I've done this but it has made no difference. Why?

Comment: You edited the app registration manifest for the API right? That should change the token to v2..

Comment: Yes I changed the manifest for both the client and the api

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to acquire the token?

Comment: I've just prepared an example token to post using jwt.io and the token now contains the expected issuer. eg https://login.microsoftonline.com.  strangely the audience has changed from api://myapi  to my clientId Guid.  I havent changed any of my code since posting the question so I can only assume that setting "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2   actually worked but took several hours to come into effect.

Comment: In case, would like to set this programatically through Graph SDK, hope this answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/69341905/2933389

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So seems that changing the acceptedTokenVersion to 2 in the manifest did change but it just took time to take effect.

And yes the audience is always the client id based on my tests in v2 tokens.

Comment: How long does it take for this change to take effect? I made the change 30+ min ago and still getting v1 tokens back from v2 endpoint.

Comment: So you changed the accepted token version for the API you are asking the token for?

Comment: yes I set `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2` in the manifest of the app registration ("client") I'm using in the token request. I am using `grant_type: password`, in case that matters.

Comment: @BobMeyers What is the `scope` you are using? The reason I'm asking is that it is important to set that property value on the app to which the token is requested, not the client app (unless the app is requesting a token for itself of course).

Comment: Is there anyway to set `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2` programatically instead of updating in manifest manually?

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti yes,

az rest --method PATCH --headers "Content-Type=application/json" --uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$app_object_id/ --body '{"api":{"requestedAccessTokenVersion": 2}}'

Comment: Its been more than 12 hours that I changed in Manifest file. But the issuer URL is not yet updated :(

Comment: @VikiCullen did it update in the end? if yes, after how much time?

Answer (score 6):

If you are authenticating an api, then add the follow code in startup class:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
   {
      options.Authority  = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/v2.0";
      options.Audience   = "<Audience>";
      options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer 
                         = "https://sts.windows.net/<TenantId>/";
   });
```

The code above, inform the correct `Issuer`.

Comment: hi, How can we get Audience and Issuer from Azure? Please help me.

Comment: Audience you can in azure b2c >> app registration >> expose an api >> Add Scope >> {choose one guid}, and your audience will be: api://{guid}

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer of change `acceptedTokenVersion` to `2` is the right one. However, there is a bit more nuance as well:

- The reason why it may take some time to take affect is your client libraries, such as MSAL for javascript, can cache tokens and will continue to serve up the version 1 token for some period of time. I suspect this is why the accepted answer and comments are talking about how it took several hours to take effect.
- If you are using msal-browser for node.js and follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/docs/performance.md#bypass-authority-metadata-resolution) to improve performance you need to take special care that you use the version 2.0 endpoint for filling in the `authorityMetadata`. At the time of writing this the instructions are incomplete and misleading making it easy to make this mistake.